# Ubuntu 22.04 "ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol" errors on Asus X705UA

Tags: asus, acpi

Running Ubuntu 22.04, Kernel 5.15.0-40-generic x86_64
Since the last kernel update about 3 weeks ago, I have started to get the following errors:-

I have updated the ASUS laptop with the latest BIOS version V322 - but this has done nothing.

```
ACPI errors shown here...
[    0.341051] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[    0.341075] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR01._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.341153] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[    0.341171] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR02._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.341250] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.PR00._CPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[    0.341268] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PR.PR03._CPC due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.342812] ACPI: thermal: Thermal Zone [THRM] (34 C)
```

Comment: Can you still boot? Does the computer continue to work fine? If so, you can ignore all those "ACPI Error" statements. It is normal to see "errors" on boot and so long as everything seems to work fine you can safely ignore them.

Comment: I've got exactly the same ACPI Error messages after a firmware update of a Lenovo ThinkPad P72 and also with (K)ubuntu 22.04

Answer (score 20):

This is a known bug in certain versions of the Linux kernel (5.12.x and 5.17.2+, among others) with [Collaborative Processor Performance Control (CPPC)](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/acpi/cppc_sysfs.html) affecting Intel CPUs. The kernel guys are working on a patch:

https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213023

Comment: Thanks for the information ! Can you tell when they will be releasing the bugfix for Linux Ubuntu, I am using 22.04 and I am getting the same error as of now.

Answer (score 8):

To get rid of these messages while booting, you can add `loglevel=3` to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in etc/default/grub, so that it will look like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash loglevel=3"
```

then update grub using command:
`sudo update-grub`

Note that, adding 'loglevel=3' simply disables the non-critical error but doesn't resolve it. Since this is an active issue reported on bugzilla and has been resolved for 5.18.xx kernels, you can try upgrading your linux kernel to this version using software and updates. Hopefully, it could be resolved soon for 5.15.XX and other kernels. To get more info on why this happens @LordBoltar has explained very well in [this](https://www.linux.org/threads/acpi-error-after-installing-ubuntu-22-04.40993/post-164118) thread.

Comment: Thanks, so basically, your saying the ACPI bootup messages were warnings ?

Comment: Issue still persists in kernel 6.1. The bug entry claims it was re-introduced in 5.17

Answer (score 0):

in my case I had similar error

```
 ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, while evaluating GPE method [_L09] (20220331/evgpe-511)
 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_GPE._L09.D1F0], AE_NOT_FOUND (20220331/psargs-330)

No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_L09]
No Arguments are initialized for method [_L09]
```

and for me this was the solution

```
echo "mask" > /sys/firmware/acpi/interrupts/gpe09
```

but after reboot you need to rerun this command again

Answer (score -3):

It was solved to me after typing `update-manager –d` on the terminal.

Hope it can be useful to you.

Reference: https://phoenixnap.com/kb/how-to-update-kernel-ubuntu

Comment: `-d` upgrades to a development release, which may not be stable enough for many people.