# Can someone explain/help me understand/solve this ACPI error bug?

Tags: boot

My current issue is every time I boot up my system, I receive these error codes. This is a fresh install with the minimal option selected, no updates or 3rd party proprietary drivers selected on the installation.

Current build is as follows:

Motherboard - Gigabyte B365M-DS3H
CPU - Intel i3 8100
RAM - G.SKILL DDR4-2666 64GB (16x4)
Storage - Samsung SSD980 1TB

System information:

Ubuntu 22.04
GNOME version: 42.0
Windowing system: Wayland

I also had two other error codes which I seem to have solved (only saying that because they are no longer appearing in the boot screen). One was regarding SGX which I enabled in the BIOS and that went away. The other was bcma-pci-bridge which I found related to my wi-fi card installed. I solved that by installing a driver through the CLI. I believe that is everything.

[image]

Comment: This suggests they could just be warnings. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416198/ubuntu-22-04-acpi-bios-error-bug-could-not-resolve-symbol-errors-on-asus-x7  Is everything work ok otherwise?

Comment: Again this suggests there is no real world impact https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=266085. However the final posts suggest it’s fixed in kernel 5.12.10 or 5.12.11. What’s your kernel?

Comment: As of right now everything seems to be functioning as it should (that i know of), but then why the codes you know. Seems like something is amiss. The command "uname -r" output 5.15.0-40-generic as my kernel version.

Comment: errors/warnings on boot are perfectly normal, and you can safely ignore them if everything is working fine otherwise.

Comment: Is there a way to remove this dialogue/codes from the bootup process?

Comment: I wouldn’t do that because other errors might crop up in the future

Comment: Thank you @PonJar; you answered what my followup question was going to be.

Comment: It did help me understand a bit more as to what these ACPI codes are and how they can be more annoying than actually harmful. Thank you @ArturMeinild.