# My laptop is muted since i installed Ubuntu

Tags: sound, asus, bios, realtek

I recently got an Asus Vivobook. It worked perfectly on Windows but since I moved on Ubuntu (20.04 and 22.04), I don't have any sound from the speakers.

My sound device is : HDA Intel PCH, ALC294

I tried to:

1. reinstall Ubuntu 20.04 and then install Ubuntu 22.04
2. edit the `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` file as suggested here: https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/audio_intel_hda

None of the above worked.

`lspci -v` command returns this:

```
0000:00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20) (prog-if 80)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 32, IRQ 185, IOMMU group 14
    Memory at 612f288000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Memory at 612f000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Capabilities: &lt;access denied&gt;
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
```

PS: I have this error at startup that could be a way, but I have no idea of what it is:

[image: error at startup]

I am very new to Ubuntu, so I'm sorry if it's a basic question, but I haven't found any solution until now.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: I had the same problem with a Asus Zenbook UX463F since the 22.04 upgrade and this worked for me : https://www.linux.org/threads/solved-asus-zenbook-15-ux534f-realtek-hd-audio-problem.27384/post-94479

Answer (score 0):

Add `loglevel=3` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `etc/default/grub`, so that it will look like this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash loglevel=3"
```

Then update GRUB using this command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

That's it.

Note that the above didnt't fix the `ACPI BIOS Error`, but now my speakers are working perfectly.

- Source: [Ubuntu 22.04 "ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol" errors on Asus X705UA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416198/ubuntu-22-04-acpi-bios-error-bug-could-not-resolve-symbol-errors-on-asus-x7)