# Kubuntu 23.04 not booting with the 6.2 kernel

Tags: boot, nvidia, kernel, kubuntu

After upgrading to Kubuntu 23.04, Kubuntu gets stuck here:

[image]

If I switch to the 5.19 kernel via grub, it boots perfectly fine into Kubuntu 23.04, but if I leave it on the default 6.2 kernel, it just hangs here.

I have unplugged all devices from the laptop since I was previously seeing `hid-generic item 0 0 0 12 parsing failed` and restarted, but it continues to hang on the 6.2 kernel.

The laptop has a Quadro P2000 and an Intel graphics; for some reason it also won't switch to the Quadro anymore when using `sudo prime-select nvidia`. Not sure if that's related to the 6.2 kernel not booting.

[image]

I've already done

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
All the available drivers are already installed.
```

Switching to the Nouveau driver instead of the Nvidia driver makes no difference, it still hangs on boot.

This link suggests adding `loglevel=3` to grub, although that doesn't do anything of significance - instead now I'm hanging at a blank screen instead of the above posted errors:
[Ubuntu 22.04 "ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol" errors on Asus X705UA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416198/ubuntu-22-04-acpi-bios-error-bug-could-not-resolve-symbol-errors-on-asus-x7)

`boot.log` shows the following (I'm not sure if this is the logs for when it was hanging, I'm only seeing one entry for this morning even though I rebooted twice, first into the 6.2 kernel which didn't boot and then again into the working one)

```
------------ Fri Apr 28 08:18:45 CEST 2023 ------------
/dev/mapper/kubuntu--vg-root: clean, 2977642/31162368 files, 110015678/124644352 blocks
[  OK  ] Reached target network-pre.target - Preparation for Network.
         Mounting proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount - Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System...
[  OK  ] Finished systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service - Create Volatile Files and Directories.
         Starting systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution...
         Starting systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization...
         Starting systemd-update-utmp.service - Record System Boot/Shutdown in UTMP...
[  OK  ] Mounted proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount - Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System.
[  OK  ] Finished systemd-binfmt.service - Set Up Additional Binary Formats.
[  OK  ] Finished systemd-update-utmp.service - Record System Boot/Shutdown in UTMP.
[  OK  ] Finished apparmor.service - Load AppArmor profiles.
[  OK  ] Started haveged.service - Entropy Daemon based on the HAVEGE algorithm.
         Starting snapd.apparmor.service - Load AppArmor profiles managed internally by snapd...
[  OK  ] Started systemd-timesyncd.service - Network Time Synchronization.
[  OK  ] Reached target time-set.target - System Time Set.
[  OK  ] Finished snapd.apparmor.service - Load AppArmor profiles managed internally by snapd.
[  OK  ] Started systemd-resolved.service - Network Name Resolution.
[  OK  ] Reached target nss-lookup.target - Host and Network Name Lookups.
[  OK  ] Reached target sysinit.target - System Initialization.
[  OK  ] Started acpid.path - ACPI Events Check.
[  OK  ] Started cups.path - CUPS Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Started whoopsie.path - Start whoopsie on modification of the /var/crash directory.
[  OK  ] Started anacron.timer - Trigger anacron every hour.
[  OK  ] Started apt-daily.timer - Daily apt download activities.
[  OK  ] Started apt-daily-upgrade.timer - Daily apt upgrade and clean activities.
[  OK  ] Started dpkg-db-backup.timer - Daily dpkg database backup timer.
[  OK  ] Started e2scrub_all.timer - Periodic ext4 Online Metadata Check for All Filesystems.
[  OK  ] Started fstrim.timer - Discard unused blocks once a week.
[  OK  ] Started fwupd-refresh.timer - Refresh fwupd metadata regularly.
[  OK  ] Started logrotate.timer - Daily rotation of log files.
[  OK  ] Started man-db.timer - Daily man-db regeneration.
[  OK  ] Started motd-news.timer - Message of the Day.
[  OK  ] Started plocate-updatedb.timer - Update the plocate database daily.
[  OK  ] Started systemd-tmpfiles-clean.timer - Daily Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
[  OK  ] Started ua-timer.timer - Ubuntu Advantage Timer for running repeated jobs.
[  OK  ] Reached target paths.target - Path Units.
[  OK  ] Listening on acpid.socket - ACPID Listen Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on avahi-daemon.socket - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack Activation Socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on cups.socket - CUPS Scheduler.
[  OK  ] Listening on dbus.socket - D-Bus System Message Bus Socket.
         Starting docker.socket - Docker Socket for the API...
         Starting snapd.socket - Socket activation for snappy daemon...
[  OK  ] Listening on spice-vdagentd.socket - Activation socket for spice guest agent daemon.
[  OK  ] Listening on ssh.socket - OpenBSD Secure Shell server socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on uuidd.socket - UUID daemon activation socket.
[  OK  ] Listening on docker.socket - Docker Socket for the API.
[  OK  ] Listening on snapd.socket - Socket activation for snappy daemon.
[  OK  ] Reached target sockets.target - Socket Units.
[  OK  ] Reached target basic.target - Basic System.
[  OK  ] Started acpid.service - ACPI event daemon.
[  OK  ] Started anacron.service - Run anacron jobs.
         Starting apport.service - automatic crash report generation...
         Starting avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
         Starting dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus...
[  OK  ] Started dmesg.service - Save initial kernel messages after boot.
         Starting e2scrub_reap.service - Remove Stale Online ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots...
[  OK  ] Reached target getty.target - Login Prompts.
         Starting gpu-manager.service - Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes...
         Starting grub-common.service - Record successful boot for GRUB...
[  OK  ] Started irqbalance.service - irqbalance daemon.
         Starting lm-sensors.service - Initialize hardware monitoring sensors...
         Starting nvidia-persistenced.service - NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...
         Starting polkit.service - Authorization Manager...
         Starting power-profiles-daemon.service - Power Profiles daemon...
         Starting rsyslog.service - System Logging Service...
         Starting secureboot-db.service - Secure Boot updates for DB and DBX...
         Starting smartmontools.service - Self Monitoring and Reporting Technology (SMART) Daemon...
[  OK  ] Started snapd.aa-prompt-listener.service - Userspace listener for prompt events.
[  OK  ] Reached target getty-pre.target - Preparation for Logins.
         Starting snapd.service - Snap Daemon...
[  OK  ] Reached target nss-user-lookup.target - User and Group Name Lookups.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd-nss.socket - SSSD NSS Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd-autofs.socket - SSSD AutoFS Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd-pac.socket - SSSD PAC Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd-pam-priv.socket - SSSD PAM Service responder private socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd-pam.socket - SSSD PAM Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd-ssh.socket - SSSD SSH Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd-sudo.socket - SSSD Sudo Service responder socket.
         Starting accounts-daemon.service - Accounts Service...
[  OK  ] Started cron.service - Regular background program processing daemon.
         Starting systemd-logind.service - User Login Management...
         Starting udisks2.service - Disk Manager...
[  OK  ] Finished e2scrub_reap.service - Remove Stale Online ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots.
[  OK  ] Started dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus.
[  OK  ] Finished gpu-manager.service - Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
[  OK  ] Started nvidia-persistenced.service - NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
[  OK  ] Started polkit.service - Authorization Manager.
         Starting ModemManager.service - Modem Manager...
         Starting NetworkManager.service - Network Manager...
         Starting gdm3.service - LSB: GNOME Display Manager...
         Starting wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant...
[  OK  ] Started smartmontools.service - Self Monitoring and Reporting Technology (SMART) Daemon.
[  OK  ] Finished lm-sensors.service - Initialize hardware monitoring sensors.
[  OK  ] Started gdm3.service - LSB: GNOME Display Manager.
[  OK  ] Started avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
[  OK  ] Finished grub-common.service - Record successful boot for GRUB.
[  OK  ] Started power-profiles-daemon.service - Power Profiles daemon.
         Starting grub-initrd-fallback.service - GRUB failed boot detection...
         Starting modprobe@drm.service - Load Kernel Module drm...
[  OK  ] Finished modprobe@drm.service - Load Kernel Module drm.
[  OK  ] Started wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant.
[  OK  ] Finished secureboot-db.service - Secure Boot updates for DB and DBX.
[  OK  ] Finished grub-initrd-fallback.service - GRUB failed boot detection.
[  OK  ] Started NetworkManager.service - Network Manager.
[  OK  ] Reached target network.target - Network.
         Starting NetworkManager-wait-online.service - Network Manager Wait Online...
         Starting containerd.service - containerd container runtime...
         Starting cups.service - CUPS Scheduler...
         Starting nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
         Starting openvpn.service - OpenVPN service...
         Starting postgresql@11-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 11-main...
         Starting postgresql@12-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 12-main...
         Starting postgresql@13-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 13-main...
         Starting postgresql@14-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 14-main...
         Starting postgresql@15-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 15-main...
[  OK  ] Started snap.cups.cups-browsed.service - Service for snap application cups.cups-browsed.
[  OK  ] Started snap.cups.cupsd.service - Service for snap application cups.cupsd.
         Starting systemd-user-sessions.service - Permit User Sessions...
[  OK  ] Started containerd.service - containerd container runtime.
[  OK  ] Finished openvpn.service - OpenVPN service.
ket activation for snappy daemon.
[  OK  ] Reached target sockets.target - Socket Units.
[  OK  ] Reached target basic.target - Basic System.
[  OK  ] Started acpid.service - ACPI event daemon.
[  OK  ] Started anacron.service - Run anacron jobs.
         Starting apport.serviceomatic crash report generation...
         Starting avahi-daemon.serv…e - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
         Starting dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus...
[  OK  ] Started dmesg.service …nitial kernel messages after boot.
         Starting e2scrub_reap.serv…e ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots...
[  OK  ] Reached target getty.target - Login Prompts.
         Starting gpu-manager.servi…nd deal with any system changes...
         Starting grub-common.servi…Record successful boot for GRUB...
[  OK  ] Started irqbalance.service - irqbalance daemon.
         Starting lm-sensors.servic…ize hardware monitoring sensors...
         Starting nvidia-persistenc…[0m - NVIDIA Persistence Daemon...
         Starting polkit.service - Authorization Manager...
         Starting power-profiles-da…ice - Power Profiles daemon...
         Starting rsyslog.service - System Logging Service...
         Starting secureboot-db.ser…ure Boot updates for DB and DBX...
         Starting smartmontools.ser…rting Technology (SMART) Daemon...
[  OK  ] Started snapd.aa-prompt-li…rspace listener for prompt events.
[  OK  ] Reached target getty-pre.target - Preparation for Logins.
         Starting snapd.service - Snap Daemon...
[  OK  ] Reached target nss-user-lo…[0m - User and Group Name Lookups.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd…SSSD NSS Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd…D AutoFS Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd…SSSD PAC Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd… Service responder private socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd…SSSD PAM Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd…SSSD SSH Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd…SSD Sudo Service responder socket.
         Starting accounts-daemon.service - Accounts Service...
[  OK  ] Started cron.service -…kground program processing daemon.
         Starting systemd-logind.se…ice - User Login Management...
         Starting udisks2.service - Disk Manager...
[  OK  ] Finished e2scrub_reap.serv…ine ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots.
[  OK  ] Started dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus.
[  OK  ] Finished gpu-manager.servi… and deal with any system changes.
[  OK  ] Started nvidia-persistence…e - NVIDIA Persistence Daemon.
         Starting NetworkManager.service - Network Manager...
         Starting gdm3.service - LSB: GNOME Display Manager...
         Starting wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant...
[  OK  ] Started smartmontools.serv…porting Technology (SMART) Daemon.
[  OK  ] Started gdm3.service - LSB: GNOME Display Manager.
[  OK  ] Started polkit.service - Authorization Manager.
[  OK  ] Started avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
[  OK  ] Finished lm-sensors.servic…alize hardware monitoring sensors.
[  OK  ] Started power-profiles-dae…rvice - Power Profiles daemon.
[  OK  ] Finished grub-common.servi…- Record successful boot for GRUB.
         Starting ModemManager.service - Modem Manager...
         Starting grub-initrd-fallb…0m - GRUB failed boot detection...
         Starting modprobe@drm.service - Load Kernel Module drm...
[  OK  ] Started wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant.
[  OK  ] Finished secureboot-db.ser…ecure Boot updates for DB and DBX.
[  OK  ] Finished modprobe@drm.service - Load Kernel Module drm.
[  OK  ] Finished grub-initrd-fallb… - GRUB failed boot detection.
[  OK  ] Started NetworkManager.service - Network Manager.
[  OK  ] Reached target network.target - Network.
         Starting NetworkManager-wa…m - Network Manager Wait Online...
         Starting containerd.servic… - containerd container runtime...
         Starting cups.service - CUPS Scheduler...
         Starting nginx.service…rver and a reverse proxy server...
         Starting openvpn.service - OpenVPN service...
         Starting postgresql@11-mai…0m - PostgreSQL Cluster 11-main...
         Starting postgresql@12-mai…0m - PostgreSQL Cluster 12-main...
         Starting postgresql@13-mai…0m - PostgreSQL Cluster 13-main...
         Starting postgresql@14-mai…0m - PostgreSQL Cluster 14-main...
         Starting postgresql@15-mai…0m - PostgreSQL Cluster 15-main...
[  OK  ] Started snap.cups.cups-bro…nap application cups.cups-browsed.
[  OK  ] Started snap.cups.cupsd.se…e for snap application cups.cupsd.
         Starting systemd-user-sess…vice - Permit User Sessions...
[  OK  ] Started containerd.service…0m - containerd container runtime.
[  OK  ] Finished openvpn.service - OpenVPN service.
ket activation for snappy daemon.
[  OK  ] Reached target sockets.target - Socket Units.
[  OK  ] Reached target basic.target - Basic System.
[  OK  ] Started acpid.service - ACPI event daemon.
         Starting alsa-restore.serv…- Save/Restore Sound Card State...
[  OK  ] Started anacron.service - Run anacron jobs.
         Starting apport.serviceomatic crash report generation...
         Starting avahi-daemon.serv…e - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack...
         Starting bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service...
         Starting dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus...
[  OK  ] Started dmesg.service …nitial kernel messages after boot.
         Starting e2scrub_reap.serv…e ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots...
[  OK  ] Reached target getty.target - Login Prompts.
         Starting gpu-manager.servi…nd deal with any system changes...
         Starting grub-common.servi…Record successful boot for GRUB...
[  OK  ] Started irqbalance.service - irqbalance daemon.
         Starting lm-sensors.servic…ize hardware monitoring sensors...
         Starting polkit.service - Authorization Manager...
         Starting power-profiles-da…ice - Power Profiles daemon...
         Starting rsyslog.service - System Logging Service...
         Starting secureboot-db.ser…ure Boot updates for DB and DBX...
         Starting smartmontools.ser…rting Technology (SMART) Daemon...
[  OK  ] Reached target getty-pre.target - Preparation for Logins.
         Starting snapd.service - Snap Daemon...
[  OK  ] Reached target nss-user-lo…[0m - User and Group Name Lookups.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd…SSSD NSS Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd…D AutoFS Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd…SSSD PAC Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd… Service responder private socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd…SSSD PAM Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd…SSSD SSH Service responder socket.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for sssd…SSD Sudo Service responder socket.
         Starting accounts-daemon.service - Accounts Service...
[  OK  ] Started cron.service -…kground program processing daemon.
         Starting systemd-logind.se…ice - User Login Management...
         Starting udisks2.service - Disk Manager...
[  OK  ] Started systemd-rfkill.ser…- Load/Save RF Kill Switch Status.
         Starting systemd-backlight…ess of leds:dell::kbd_backlight...
[  OK  ] Finished alsa-restore.serv…m - Save/Restore Sound Card State.
[  OK  ] Reached target sound.target - Sound Card.
[  OK  ] Finished grub-common.servi…- Record successful boot for GRUB.
         Starting grub-initrd-fallb…0m - GRUB failed boot detection...
[  OK  ] Finished e2scrub_reap.serv…ine ext4 Metadata Check Snapshots.
[  OK  ] Finished lm-sensors.servic…alize hardware monitoring sensors.
[  OK  ] Finished secureboot-db.ser…ecure Boot updates for DB and DBX.
[  OK  ] Started dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus.
[  OK  ] Started smartmontools.serv…porting Technology (SMART) Daemon.
         Starting NetworkManager.service - Network Manager...
         Starting gdm3.service - LSB: GNOME Display Manager...
         Starting wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant...
[  OK  ] Finished grub-initrd-fallb… - GRUB failed boot detection.
[  OK  ] Started gdm3.service - LSB: GNOME Display Manager.
[  OK  ] Started avahi-daemon.service - Avahi mDNS/DNS-SD Stack.
[  OK  ] Started polkit.service - Authorization Manager.
         Starting ModemManager.service - Modem Manager...
[  OK  ] Started power-profiles-dae…rvice - Power Profiles daemon.
         Starting modprobe@drm.service - Load Kernel Module drm...
[  OK  ] Started wpa_supplicant.service - WPA supplicant.
[  OK  ] Finished modprobe@drm.service - Load Kernel Module drm.
[  OK  ] Started bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service.
[  OK  ] Reached target bluetooth.target - Bluetooth Support.
[  OK  ] Stopped target bluetooth.target - Bluetooth Support.
         Starting systemd-hostnamed.service - Hostname Service...
[  OK  ] Started NetworkManager.service - Network Manager.
[  OK  ] Reached target network.target - Network.
         Starting NetworkManager-wa…m - Network Manager Wait Online...
         Starting containerd.servic… - containerd container runtime...
         Starting cups.service - CUPS Scheduler...
         Starting nginx.service…rver and a reverse proxy server...
         Starting openvpn.service - OpenVPN service...
         Starting postgresql@11-mai…0m - PostgreSQL Cluster 11-main...
         Starting postgresql@12-mai…0m - PostgreSQL Cluster 12-main...
         Starting postgresql@13-mai…0m - PostgreSQL Cluster 13-main...
         Starting postgresql@14-mai…0m - PostgreSQL Cluster 14-main...
         Starting postgresql@15-mai…0m - PostgreSQL Cluster 15-main...
[  OK  ] Started snap.cups.cups-bro…nap application cups.cups-browsed.
[  OK  ] Started snap.cups.cupsd.se…e for snap application cups.cupsd.
         Starting systemd-user-sess…vice - Permit User Sessions...
[  OK  ] Finished systemd-backlight…tness of leds:dell::kbd_backlight.
[  OK  ] Started containerd.service…0m - containerd container runtime.
[  OK  ] Finished openvpn.service - OpenVPN service.
[  OK  ] Finished systemd-user-sess…ervice - Permit User Sessions.
[  OK  ] Started systemd-logind.service - User Login Management.
         Starting plymouth-quit.ser… Terminate Plymouth Boot Screen...
         Starting setvtrgb.service - Set console scheme...
[  OK  ] Started unattended-upgrade…0m - Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.
[  OK  ] Finished setvtrgb.service - Set console scheme.
[  OK  ] Created slice system-getty.slice - Slice /system/getty.
```

Any ideas what I can try to boot with the 6.2 kernel?

Comment: There are too many ideas to list them all in a reasonable amount of time. Can you narrow it down, a lot.

Comment: @mikewhatever, this machine has started on Kubuntu 18 and upgraded through all the versions (LTS and non-LTS versions) so far without issues. I don't fully know what is remnants from the older versions and what is supposed to be there.
Also not sure where to start looking for clues ... I can post the boot.log and dmesg output here if that is useful?

Comment: Related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2012559

Answer (score 1):

This is what solved it for me on Ubuntu 23.04 on a Lenovo ThinkPad P51 with NVIDIA Quadro M1200:

```
sudo apt instal nvidia-driver-515
```

and reboot. This led to working kernel 6.2 and proprietary graphics drivers.

I ended up trying that as per comments at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2012559

Previously I had 510. It also breaks if I try to install 525, even though it is marked as "Tested" in "Additional Drivers", making boot fail with:

```
Finished apport-autoreport.service - Process error reports when automatic reporting is enabled.
nvidia-modeset: ERROR: GPU:0: Idling display engine timed out: 0x0000947d:0:0:407
(1 of 2) Job systemd-backlight@backlight: nvidia_e.service/start running (32s no limit)
```

[It is a minefield](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i2lhwb_OckQ).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue upgrading to Ubuntu 23.04 on a laptop with both intel hd and nvidia graphics cards. I found that removing the nvidia drivers and installing the open source nouveau driver allowed the system to boot normally. Here are the commands I used:

```
sudo dpkg -P $(dpkg -l |grep nvidia-driver | awk '{print $2}')
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt update 
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
shutdown -r now
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't do anything for my setup, it still hangs. :-(
Maybe that means graphics is not the issue on my machine.

Comment: So far NIVIDIA drivers (3.90 in my case due to an old video card) still don't work on XORG or Wayland with in gnome or Ubuntu at login.. using 23.04 kernel 6.2, 6.3 6.4 and 6.5rc1. Haven't tried the video drivers directly from NVIDIA's website though. only the ones with sudo apt-get ..

Answer (score 0):

Having the same problem using UBUNTU on an older Notebook from 22.10 to 23.04. always use this computer to validate an upgrade before upgrading

other PC's.
This computer NEVER EVER had an issue after an update and was used for many years. Also has NVIDIA and Intel hardware. After splash screen, blank screen with blinking errors. Happens just after launching the gnome-desktop.  Tried every posted here and everything on the web. Nothing works.  Switched to boot 23.04 with the 5.x kernel, same problem. Help...

ran:

```
sudo apt install nouveau-firmware
```

since it seems it was missing
but still did not fix it.
startx. gives and error - no screens found. (Because default is wayland?)

Finally got back to my desktop after removing NVIDA drivers. Guess that probably forces it back to use nouveau driver.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge '^nvidia-.*'
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Now it runs 6.2.0.20- generic. with an Gnome desktop.

Perhaps something major changed related to video driver from 22.10 from 23.04. that older hardware now suffers from.

Not sure if there is an easier command line option to switch between drivers.

P.S: X11 and Wayland both seem to run fine.

Comment: you can switch between drivers using: `sudo prime-select nvidia|intel|on-demand|query`

Switching to nouveau drivers didn't do anything on my setup, glad it worked for you.

Comment: Thanks for that hint. Very useful will try it out once NVIDIA drivers are fixed or supported.  Perhaps  boot from an USB stick with 22.10 or an older version or swap the boot disk to further nail down the root cause of your specific problem ?

Comment: I am on 23.04 now and NVIDIA's drivers are still not working with on kernels 6.2 6.3 , 6.4 and 6.5rc1. I need to use NVIDIA 3.90 drivers due to an old video card.