# ACPI BIOS Error (bug) on new build PC

Tags: boot, acpi

I recently build a new PC. Now I'm trying to start my ubuntu (not sure which version) workspace from an usb-drive on this PC and I get the error message (below) when booting. I have no clue what to do... I have no issues with the same USB on a older laptop.

[   0.302630] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [_SB.PCI0.GPP7.UP00.DP40.UP00.DP68], AE_NOT_FOUND (20190816/dswload2-163)
[   0.302637] ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20190816/psobject-221)
[   1.012979] hub 10-0:1.0: config failed, hub doesn't have any ports! (err -19)
[   3.824849] sd 12:0:0:0: [sda] No Caching mode page found
[   3.824876] sd 12:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
[   8.822917] sd 12:0:0:0: Failed to get diagnostic page 0x1
[   8.822928] sd 12:0:0:0: Failed to bind enclosure -19
[   9.446851] db_root: cannot open etc/target

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSQVw.jpg)

My build:
AMD Ryzen 7700X
Asus TUF GAMING X670E-PLUS WIFI
Radeon RX 6950 XT Phantom Gaming D 16G

Hope anyone can help me out! Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 22.04 "ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol" errors on Asus X705UA](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1416198/ubuntu-22-04-acpi-bios-error-bug-could-not-resolve-symbol-errors-on-asus-x7)